# Don't understand why the fillter function in dplyr says an object doesn't exist when the dataset that contains the object displays when called

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am working my way through the introduction to dplyr tutorial.  I have loaded the required dataset as shown below:

```
flights
# A tibble: 336,776 x 19
   year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay carrier flight tailnum origin dest  air_time distance
  <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>     <dbl> <chr>    <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830            819        11 UA        1545 N14228  EWR    IAH        227     1400
2  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850            830        20 UA        1714 N24211  LGA    IAH        227     1416
3  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923            850        33 AA        1141 N619AA  JFK    MIA        160     1089
4  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18 B6         725 N804JB  JFK    BQN        183     1576
5  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25 DL         461 N668DN  LGA    ATL        116      762
# ... with 336,771 more rows, and 3 more variables: hour <dbl>, minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>
```

And here's another look at the dataset using the `str()` command.

```
> str(flights)
tibble [336,776 x 19] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ year          : int [1:336776] 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 ...
 $ month         : int [1:336776] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day           : int [1:336776] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dep_time      : int [1:336776] 517 533 542 544 554 554 555 557 557 558 ...
 $ sched_dep_time: int [1:336776] 515 529 540 545 600 558 600 600 600 600 ...
 $ dep_delay     : num [1:336776] 2 4 2 -1 -6 -4 -5 -3 -3 -2 ...
 $ arr_time      : int [1:336776] 830 850 923 1004 812 740 913 709 838 753 ...
 $ sched_arr_time: int [1:336776] 819 830 850 1022 837 728 854 723 846 745 ...
 $ arr_delay     : num [1:336776] 11 20 33 -18 -25 12 19 -14 -8 8 ...
 $ carrier       : chr [1:336776] "UA" "UA" "AA" "B6" ...
 $ flight        : int [1:336776] 1545 1714 1141 725 461 1696 507 5708 79 301 ...
 $ tailnum       : chr [1:336776] "N14228" "N24211" "N619AA" "N804JB" ...
 $ origin        : chr [1:336776] "EWR" "LGA" "JFK" "JFK" ...
 $ dest          : chr [1:336776] "IAH" "IAH" "MIA" "BQN" ...
 $ air_time      : num [1:336776] 227 227 160 183 116 150 158 53 140 138 ...
 $ distance      : num [1:336776] 1400 1416 1089 1576 762 ...
 $ hour          : num [1:336776] 5 5 5 5 6 5 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ minute        : num [1:336776] 15 29 40 45 0 58 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ time_hour     : POSIXct[1:336776], format: "2013-01-01 05:00:00" "2013-01-01 05:00:00" "2013-01-01 05:00:00" "2013-01-01 05:00:00" ...
```

But, when I attempt to filter the data using the `filter()` command, I get the following error:

```
> filter(flights, dest == "DTW")
Error in filter(flights, dest == "DTW") : object 'dest' not found
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you attached dplyr via library(dplyr)? Try with `dplyr::filter(flights, dest == "DTW")`.

Comment: Oops, OK, now this is embarrasing.  I started a new session and forgot to load tidyverse!

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the data to filter function
data %>%
filter().

Comment: Thx.  Actually, now that I've loaded tidyverse it works with or without piping the data into the filter command.